# What is the reason for decrease in electron donating tendency with increase in no. Of bonds

Tags: organic-chemistry, electronegativity

The order of electron donating tendency with polar protic solvent goes as

$$\ce{RCH2 > RCH=CH > RC=C-}$$

However, I think that with the increase in the number of bonds the electronegativity between $\ce{R}$ and $\ce{C}$ increased and the leaving group should rather be able to leave easily. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the first thing to note is that the "electron donating" tendency follows the given order because the electronegativity of "carbon" increases. You could explain this with something as simple as the hybridisation theory. Notice the hybridisation difference between the carbon atoms in the first and second compound. $sp^2$ hybridised carbon atoms have more electronegativity than $sp^3$ ones(Because of more percentage of s character). Therefore carbon atoms with $sp^3$ hybridisation more easily share electrons than those with $sp^2$. Now between the last two, what do you mean?

If you meant $\ce{RC#C-}$ which should most likely be the case since a -1 charge is present in what you have drawn. Well here the carbon which would act as a "donor" has a $sp$ hybridisation and you could use similar arguments as stated above.
This is the reason why the order is what it is. You most probably were not wrong has you have got all the facts about electronegativity right, but looks like you have arrived at a slightly wrong result while connecting the facts and arriving at an explanation.

Also, please elaborate and explain your problem and attempt better next time.
Hope this helps, in case you find anything unanswered, feel free to comment.

Comment: i was thinking in a way that if electronegativity increse then two species have a greater difference in the electronegativity and bond should becomes more ionic but I see it becomes more covalent